# Amcharts - Combine "parseDates", "connect", and Guides functionality

Tags: amcharts

I try to make a chart, with guides and eventual data gap.

To manage gap, we need to use the option "connect : false" in the concerned graph.
Example : http://www.amcharts.com/demos/chart-with-gaps-in-data/

If I understood, "connect" option can't be apply if "parseDates" and "minPeriod" on "CategoryAxis" was not defined.
You can check this thanks to the previous link. Remove "parseDates" and "minPeriod", the "connect" option of the graph is ignored.

And in the following example : http://www.amcharts.com/demos/stacked-area/#
We use"guides". (Red area in this example)

If we add a "parseDates" to "CategoryAxis", guides disappears...

So to conclude : if we want "guides", we couldn't have "parseDates" option, and if we don't have "parseDates" option, we couldn't have "connect" graph option.

So my question is : Could we combine this 3 functions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `parseDates: true` to display gaps in graph.

When you use date-based data (`parseDates: true`) the chart automatically calculates gaps in data.

If you are using series-based data, you still have several "manual" options to specify gaps:

1) Use [`gapField`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#gapField) to specify which field in data may hold a boolean value which indicates a gap. If the gapField in data contains `true`, the chart will break the line after this data point and will display a gap.

```
"dataProvider": [ {
  "year": 1994,
  "cars": 1587,
  "motorcycles": 650,
  "bicycles": 121
}, {
  "year": 1995,
  "cars": 1567,
  "motorcycles": 683,
  "bicycles": 146,
  "gap": true
}, { // will display a gap between 1995 and 1996
  "year": 1996,
  "cars": 1617,
  "motorcycles": 691,
  "bicycles": 138
}, {
  "year": 1997,
  "cars": 1630,
  "motorcycles": 642,
  "bicycles": 127
}, {
  "year": 1998,
  "cars": 1660,
  "motorcycles": 699,
  "bicycles": 105
} ]
```

2) Omit value field for specific data point. If there's a data point which does not have particular field as specified in graph's `valueField`, it will break the line as well.

```
"dataProvider": [ {
  "year": 1994,
  "cars": 1587,
  "motorcycles": 650,
  "bicycles": 121
}, {
  "year": 1995,
  "cars": 1567,
  "motorcycles": 683,
  "bicycles": 146
}, {
  "year": 1996 // will display a gap on 1996
}, {
  "year": 1997,
  "cars": 1630,
  "motorcycles": 642,
  "bicycles": 127
}, {
  "year": 1998,
  "cars": 1660,
  "motorcycles": 699,
  "bicycles": 105
} ]
```

Comment: I tried but the gap is not showing with the setting of `graph.connect = false`, `categoryAxis.parseDates = true` and `categoryAxis.minPeriod = "mm"`. Any idea?

Comment: This is a separate question. Please email us at contact@amcharts.com and we'll resolve this. Include your chart code and data if possible.